# Conditionally filling pandas column with data from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (df1) that has a column, 'units', populated with either blank nan values or strings.

```html
df1

id   s_type  s_name  s_unit
1    t1      n1      m2
2    t1      n5      m2
3    t2      n2      NaN
4    t6      n3      each
```

I have a second dataframe, (df2), that has similar information, though without ids.

```html
df2

type  name  unit
t3    n4    cm2
t4    n2    m3
t2    n2    kg
t6    n0    Nan
```

I am struggling to develop an expression to

1. identify rows in df1 where unit is null AND
2. insert unit value from df2 in to unit column of df1 WHERE
3. df1['type'] matches df2['type'] AND df1['name'] matches df2['name']

In the above frames, the expression would populate the 'unit' column of df1 with the value of 'kg', as 'type' and 'name' both match.

Something similar to:

```html
df1.loc[df1['unit'].isnull(), 'unit'] = df2['unit'].where(
      (df1['name'] == df2['name']) & 
      (df1['type'] == df2['type']))
```

Though the above line is producing a "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects."

I have looked through the documentation and other SO questions. and am at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `left join` and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['type','name'], how='left')

df1['unit'] = df1['unit'].combine_first(df['unit_y'])
print (df1)
   id type name  unit
0   1   t1   n1    m2
1   2   t1   n5    m2
2   3   t2   n2    kg
3   4   t6   n3  each
```

---

```
df1['unit'] = df1['unit'].fillna(df['unit_y'])
print (df1)
   id type name  unit
0   1   t1   n1    m2
1   2   t1   n5    m2
2   3   t2   n2    kg
3   4   t6   n3  each
```

Comment: Alternative solution looks much cleaner but doesn't seem to be working on my end. How does fillna() know how to filter by name and type?

Comment: indexes are same, because left join, so is possible use `df['unit_y']`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `df.loc[(df['unit_x'].isnull(), 'unit_x')] = df[unit_y']` and made my way from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge first and then fill na in unit with values from df2.

```
(
     pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['type','name'],how='left',suffixes=['','_y'])
         .assign(unit=lambda x: x.unit.combine_first(x.unit_y))
         .drop('unit_y',1)
)
Out[301]: 
   id type name  unit
0   1   t1   n1    m2
1   2   t1   n5    m2
2   3   t2   n2    kg
3   4   t6   n3  each
```